# Tracing socket (file) descriptor back to bound address

Tags: c#, c, linux, mono

I have a running application (C#/mono) which appears to be looping on the following system call : (I determined this via a run of strace and found that this call is currently the only being made)

```
recvfrom([sockfd], "", [length], 0, NULL, NULL)   = 0
```

Reading up on recvfrom (http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) I find the first parameter *sockfd* to be representative of a socket file descriptor.

Without stopping the application and including debug logic / extra verbosity to let me know which socket address the *sockfd* has been bound to, is there any way to look this up?

I've tried poking around for any references of where this information may be made available from the system but haven't come up with much

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lsof` command to list all open IP sockets for a program doing like this

```
lsof | grep pid.*sd.*IP
```

where

- `pid` is to be replaced by the program process id and
- `sd` is to be replaced by the socket descriptor as shown by `strace`.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
lsof -p PID -a -d FD
```

to see what descriptor `FD` of process `PID` is. You can run

```
lsof -p PID
```

to see all descriptors, sockets, and active memory maps the process uses, and

```
lsof -i4 -i6
```

to see all internet connections by all processes. The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) contains more information on the `lsof` command, but it is pretty convoluted; however, the *Examples* section is illustrative.

Comment: @alk: These are much faster than filtering the output -- that's how I found these, originally: I got fed up waiting for my `lsof | awk ...` incantations to complete. The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) is one of the messiest I know; reading anything except the Examples section tends to cause frustration.. :)